# Unable to include files in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, include, sdl-2

Recently I have been trying to setup SDL2, but I have come across an issue.

I have added the directory to the include folder into my project's Include Directories, added the directory to the lib folder to my project's Library Directories and added the .lib files to my project's Additional Dependencies. The issue is though that whenever I try to do something like `#include <SDL.h>`, it gives off a "cannot open source file" error.

Though if I do a `#include <iostream>` or something, it will work.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is exact file structure and include directories option?

Comment: For the Include directory, `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\SDL2-2.0.5\include` and the Library directory being `$(SolutionDir)Dependencies\SDL2-2.0.5\lib`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Check your paths. Also make sure you're using the same configuration you've added include paths to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried #include "SDL.h"?

Comment: Another one is getting SDL's info and then creating a new file from your solution inside VS. Or instead copying SDL file from Windows Explorer, you get it in from Visual Studio.